# Looping an item

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, printing

I need help trying to figure this out. this is before it will get looped and make a list (this is orginal data that has been printed):

```
import sys

def main():

    names = []

phylum = []

diet = []

output = ""



infile = 'animals_shortList.txt'

try :

    with open (infile, 'r') as file :
        animalList = file.readlines ()
except :

    print ('Error reading file')


animalList.sort()
print (animalList)


main()
```

output:

```
['Boar,Mammal,Omnivore\n', 'Caiman,Reptile,Carnivore\n', 
 'Cheetah,Mammal,Carnivore \n', 'Chimp,Mammal,Omnivore', 
 'Crocodile,Reptile,Carnivore\n', 'Elk,Mammal,Herbivore\n', 
 'Ibis,Bird,Carnivore\n', 'Iguana,Reptile,Herbivore\n', 
 'Robin,Bird,Omnivore\n', 'Squirrel,Mammal,Herbivore\n', 
 'Turtle,Reptile,Omnivore\n', 'Yak,Mammal,Herbivore\n']
```

Once the list has been successfully created and sorted, loop through each item in the list and prints the animal, phylum, and diet, as shown. Notice that for the purpose of printing (not in the actual list) the commas that were in the original data have been replaced with 3 spaces. Use a variable to number each printed line. In the final program, this will be the first output shown. Should be shown like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your *question*?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(animalList):
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    print(f"{i} {line[0]}  {line[1]}  {line[2]}")
```

[image]